# Conversion of GRIB and NetCDF to my database

Tags: csv, grid, data-conversion, netcdf, grib

[image]

I have downloaded "High Resolution Initial Conditions" climate forecast data for one day, it was in extension .tar.gz so I extracted it in my local directory and I get the files like in the attached image. I think, that the files without extension are GRIB data (because first word in them is "GRIB"). So I want to get data from the big files (GRIB and NetCDF formats containing climate data like temerature & pressure in grid) to my database, but they are binary. Can you recommend me some easy way for getting data from these files? I can't get any information about handling their datasets on their website.

Converting these files to .csv would be nice, but I can't find a program to convert the GRIB files.

Answer (score 1):

Using python and some available modules it is simple...

The [Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/edudownload.php) includes several [packages](http://www.enthought.com/products/epdlibraries.php), including **netCDF4**, to deal with NetCDF files!

I've never worked with GRIB files, but google tells that another python package exists, [pygrib2](http://code.google.com/p/pygrib2).

Or you can use [PyNio](http://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/Nio.shtml), a Python package that allows to read and write netCDF3 and netCDF4 classic format, and to read GRIB1 and GRIB2 files.

I don't know the ammount of data you have, but usually it is crazy to convert it to *.csv! Python is easy to learn, and suitable to work with this kind of data (with matplotlib package you can even plot it). Or, if you really need it in a *.csv, you can select with python a smaller domain, for example, or the needed variables...

Comment: I want to see what kind of values and what values are inside the GRIB files to handle them, that's why I want to convert them to csv, to see the values like some table and think about the structure, how to put them in my database. And I better have some C solution instead of python, cuz I had some programs to handle GRIBs in Fortran and it was so much painful to install that I gave up.

Comment: For a C solution I can not help you!
In case you change your mind, let me just tell you that Enthought Python Distribution is really easy to install... And then, to open a file and to see (or to plot) its values it is kind of simple as well...

Answer (score 0):

For conversion into text, look into http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib.html or http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/

Both are C programs from one of the big names in GRIB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently dealing with a similar issue.
In my case I'm trying to rely on the [GrADS](http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/grads.php) software, which can "easily" transform GRIB data into other formats.
If your dataset is not huge, then you can export it to csv using [this](http://gradsaddict.blogspot.com/2013/05/tutorial-how-to-save-data-into-txt.html) tutorial.

My dataset is 80gb in GRIB binary files, so I'm very restricted in what software I can use to handle it (no R unless I find a computer with more than 80gb of RAM).